# grpc server stops receiving messages after sending many messages simultaneously

Tags: go, grpc

I am implementing a simple grpc service where the summary of a task is to be sent to the grpc server. Everything works fine if I send less number of messages but when I begin to send like 5000 messages the server stops and gets deadline exceeded message in client side. I also tried to reconnect again but found the error message as.

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: timed out waiting for server handshake
```

The server shows no error and is alive.

I tried setting GRPC_GO_REQUIRE_HANDSHAKE=off as well but the error still prevails. I also implemented sending summary in batch but same scenerio repeated.

Is there any limitations to number of messages to be sent in grpc?

Here is my service proto

```proto
// The Result service definition.
service Result {
  rpc ConntectMaster(ConnectionRequest) returns (stream ExecutionCommand) {}
  rpc postSummary(Summary) returns(ExecutionCommand) {}
}

message Summary{

  int32 successCount = 1;
  int32 failedCount = 2;
  int32 startTime = 3;
  repeated TaskResult results = 4;
  bool isLast = 5;
  string id = 6;
}
```

postSummary implementation in sever

```golang
// PostSummary posts the summary to the master
func (server *Server) PostSummary(ctx context.Context, in *pb.Summary) (*pb.ExecutionCommand, error) {

    for i := 0; i < len(in.Results); i++ {

        res := in.Results[i]
        log.Printf("%s --> %d Res :: %s, len : %d", in.Id, i, res.Id, len(in.Results))

    }
    return &pb.ExecutionCommand{Type: stopExec}, nil
}
```

```golang
func postSummaryInBatch(executor *Executor, index int) {
    summary := pb.Summary{
        SuccessCount: int32(executor.summary.successCount),
        FailedCount:  int32(executor.summary.failedCount),
        Results:      []*pb.TaskResult{},
        IsLast:       false,
    }

    if index >= len(executor.summary.TaskResults) {
        summary.IsLast = true
        return
    }

    var to int
    batch := 500
    if (index + batch) <= len(executor.summary.TaskResults) {
        to = index + batch
    } else {
        to = len(executor.summary.TaskResults)
    }
    for i := index; i < to; i++ {
        result := executor.summary.TaskResults[i]
        taskResult := pb.TaskResult{
            Id:   result.id,
            Msg:  result.msg,
            Time: result.time,
        }
        // log.Printf("adding res : %s ", taskResult.Id)

        if result.err != nil {
            taskResult.IsError = true
        }
        summary.Results = append(summary.Results, &taskResult)
    }
    summary.Id = fmt.Sprintf("%d-%d", index, to)
    log.Printf("sent from  %d to %d ", index, to)
    postSummary(executor, &summary, 0)
    postSummaryInBatch(executor, to)
}

func postSummary(executor *Executor, summary *pb.Summary, retryCount int) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    cmd, err := client.PostSummary(ctx, summary)
    if err != nil {
        if retryCount < 3 {
            reconnect(executor)
            postSummary(executor, summary, retryCount+1)
        }
        log.Printf(err.Error())
        // log.Fatal("cannot send summary report")
    } else {
        processServerCommand(executor, cmd)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

grpc default maxReceiveMessageSize is 4MB, your grpc client probably went over that limit.

grpc uses h2 in transport layer which opens only one tcp conn and multiplex "requests" over that, reduce significant overhead compare to h1, I wouldn't worry too much for batching and will just make individual calls to grpc server.

Comment: I changed the maxReceiveMessageSize  as well as send message size to 20MB in both server and client and still the problem exists.

Comment: I guess you are correct about the message length because now when i don't send list of results in summary the message is successfully sent. What should I do if I need to send the list of results. I have tried sending in streams as well but no success.